# What are the components of English Language teaching?

Tags: english, teaching

As far as I understand teaching English means:

1. Teaching how to listen in English
2. Teaching how to speak in English
3. Teaching how to read in English
4. Teaching how to write in English

But, what are their components?

For instance, I can say:

- Teaching to speak English => (1) Pronunciation, (2) Fluency.
  (Am I correct?)

So what are the different parts of *reading*, *writing*, *listening*, and *speaking* for teaching English?

Kindly supply me with some reference along with the answer.

---

**Note:** I prepared the following:

[image]

But the sources are not authoritative because they are just webpages and not based on literature about teaching as a second / foreign language.

Comment: One thing taught implicitly when teaching English to non-natives is translation between the language of instruction or another language and English, maybe aside from some very strict monolingual teaching methods (and probably even then, if only incidently).